Insertion function for linklist is not working
My code:
def __init__(self):
    self.data = ""
    self.NextPointer = -1


def InsertLinkList(LinkList, StartPointer, FreePointer):

    if FreePointer < len(LinkList):

        data = int(input("Enter the data"))
        newNode = FreePointer
        LinkList[FreePointer].data = data
        LinkList[FreePointer].NextPointer = -1
        print(LinkList)
        FreePointer = LinkList[FreePointer].NextPointer

        if StartPointer == -1:
            StartPointer = newNode

        else:
            currentPointer = StartPointer
            while currentPointer != -1:
                lastNode = currentPointer
                currentPointer = LinkList[currentPointer].NextPointer
            LinkList[lastNode].NextPointer = newNode

    else:
        print("List is full")

    return LinkList, StartPointer, FreePointer


def PrintAll(LinkList):
    for i in range(10):
         print(LinkList[i].data)


LinkList = [Node() for i in range(10)]
StartPointer = -1
FreePointer = 0

for i in range(10):

    LinkList, StartPointer, FreePointer = InsertLinkList(LinkList, StartPointer, FreePointer)

PrintAll(LinkList)

Hello everyone,
I recently uploaded my code for link list insertion, but I am encountering some issues with its functionality. The insertion process is not happening as expected, and I am in need of assistance in understanding and resolving this problem.
If anyone has expertise in working with link lists and is willing to lend a hand, I would greatly appreciate your help.
My Output Looks like:
Enter the data1
Enter the data2
Enter the data3
Enter the data4
Enter the data5
Enter the data6
Enter the data7
Enter the data8
Enter the data9
Enter the data11
1








11


FreePointer = LinkList[FreePointer].NextPointer, this makes FreePointer -1 in the first iteration onwards. So, from next time onwards the last node is being populated

When I review your code, I'm having trouble understanding it. I am currently learning about data structures, so I can provide code for inserting into a linked list.
In my code, I have tried out many ways to insert into a linked list. I have written it in a way that everyone can understand, so if there are any doubts, let me know.
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None


class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None


    # to insert node at the beginning.
    def insert_at_beginning(self, data):
        new_node = Node(data)
        new_node.next = self.head
        self.head = new_node


    # to insert node at the specified index
    def insert_at_index(self, index, data):
        new_node = Node(data)
        if index == 0:
            new_node.next = self.head
            self.head = new_node
        else:
            current_node = self.head
            i = 0
            while current_node and i < index-1:
                current_node = current_node.next
                i += 1
            if current_node is None:
                print("index out of range")
            else:
                new_node.next = current_node.next
                current_node.next = new_node


    # to insert node before the specified node.
    def insert_before_node(self, node_data, data):
        new_node = Node(data)
        if self.head.data == node_data:
            new_node.next = self.head
            self.head = new_node
        else:
            current_node = self.head
            while current_node.next:
                if current_node.next.data == node_data:
                    new_node.next = current_node.next
                    current_node.next = new_node
                    return
                current_node = current_node.next
            print(f"{node_data} is not in the list")
    

    # to insert node after the specified node.
    def insert_after_node(self, node_data, data):
        new_node = Node(data)
        current_node = self.head
        while current_node:
            if current_node.data == node_data:
                new_node.next = current_node.next
                current_node.next = new_node
                return 
            current_node = current_node.next
        print(f"{node_data} is not in the list")
    

    # to insert node at the end.
    """ if tail is provided then we can do this function in O(1) time. """
    def append(self, data):
        new_node = Node(data)
        current_node = self.head
        while current_node.next: 
            current_node = current_node.next
        current_node.next = new_node
    

    # to print the list.
    def show(self):
        current_node = self.head
        while current_node:
            print(current_node.data, end=" ")
            current_node = current_node.next



list_1 = LinkedList()
list_1.insert_at_beginning(0)
list_1.append(1)
list_1.append(2)
list_1.insert_at_index(3, 3)
list_1.insert_after_node(3, 5)
list_1.insert_before_node(5, 4)
list_1.show()

